# Subtracting Dates of Different Formats and converting to Int

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I asked a similar question earlier and got some great feedback. I combined several answers to arrive at a solution, but it seems highly inefficient. I'm looking for a better way to get the total number of days between a variable (`ts`) and today in the form of an integer.

My Code:

```
import datetime
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
ts = ts[:10]
f = '%Y-%m-%d'
date_from_sql = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = str(now)
now = now[:10]
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(now), f)
delta = date_from_sql - now
print delta.total_seconds()/(3600*24)
```

Output:

```
67.0
```

Comment: do you want to see the difference in days between now date and ts date?

Comment: @ballpython yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delta.total_seconds()/(3600*24)` is not needed, just get use `.days`

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
ts = ts[:10]
f = '%Y-%m-%d'
date_from_sql = datetime.strptime(ts, f)
print(date_from_sql - now).days
```

If you dont want to take the time into account just use dates:

```
now = datetime.now().date()
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
ts = ts[:10]
f = '%Y-%m-%d'
date_from_sql = datetime.strptime(ts, f).date()
print(date_from_sql - now).days
```

If there is a chance the date string may be in different formats you might want [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil):

```
from dateutil import parser

now = datetime.now().date()
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
ts = parser.parse(ts).date()
print(ts - now).days
```

Comment: if the time information is stripped then you could [use `date` class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27642545/4279). Note: it doesn't matter in this case but in general, do not substruct local time from utc time (local timezone may be not UTC)

Answer (score 1):

@Padraic, yes agree, My solution also same,

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
print "days:-", (datetime.strptime(ts[:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date() - datetime.now().date()).days
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the time of the day (and timezones) i.e., the result has a day resolution; you could use `datetime.date` class and `.toordinal()` method to get the number of days:

```
from datetime import date

ts = '2015-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
date_from_sql = date(*map(int, ts[:10].split('-')))
print(date_from_sql.toordinal() - date.today().toordinal())
# -> 66
```